# Why am I getting styled is not a function when building my component library with Rollup?

Tags: javascript, next.js, styled-components, rollupjs, framer-motion

I have an internal component library that is using React, styled-components, framer-motion, Rollup and Storybook. I have a NextJS website that consumes the library and when I try to use it I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: styled is not a function
```

Bellow is the code from the built library which the error points to.

```js
var React = require('react');
var styled = require('styled-components');
var framerMotion = require('framer-motion');

const ButtonElm = styled(framerMotion.motion.button)`
    padding: ${props => props.padding};
    border-radius: ${props => props.theme.radii.default};
    font-size: ${props => props.fontSize};
    ${props => (props.bold ? "font-weight: bold" : null)};
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
`;
```

I am not sure how to address this bug at all and while I have tried some ways of changing the build configuration, nothing has worked so far. I am not sure what exactly is causing the issue.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof styled)` show?

Comment: It returns `object`

Comment: Maybe try `styled.styled()`.

Comment: This does seem to fix the issue. I am not sure how to make it so that rollupjs builds the library in a way that I don't get this error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the bug with the help of a GitHub issue on the RollupJS repository ([this one](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4438)).

I did it by adding a property of `interop: "auto"` to the rollup.config.mjs configuration file and more specifically the CommonJS output file. It ended up looking something like this:

```
output: [
        {
            file: packageJson.main,
            format: "cjs",
            sourcemap: true,
            interop: "auto",
        },
        ...
    ],
```

This changed the build file in the following way:

```
var React = require('react');
var styled = require('styled-components');

var styled__default = _interopDefault(styled);

const ButtonElm = styled__default.default(framerMotion.motion.button)`
    padding: ${props => props.padding};
    border-radius: ${props => props.theme.radii.default};
    font-size: ${props => props.fontSize};
    ${props => (props.bold ? "font-weight: bold" : null)};
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
`;
```

which ended up fixing the error. I believe it had to do with the default import of styled-components not being handled properly, resulting in an error. I was getting an object with a default property when running `console.log(typeof styled);`